# можно ли дописать js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли сделать воспроизведение треков с разрешение json ... Дело в том что на сайте зайцевнет ссылки на трек примерно такие https://zaycev.net/musicset/dl/1a5e587e27e3879953c8b8ea06f9f87a/3056654.json

и плеер петь не хочет.

```js
function cleanTempPlayList() {
  $(".tabs-pl .plstemp").empty()
}

function cleanActiveClasses() {
  $("div,a").removeClass("playlist-item-play").removeClass("play-active")
}

function createPlaySong(a) {
  if ($(".playlist-item-play").length) var e = $(".playlist-item-play").parent();
  else e = $(".playlist-item:first").parent();
  $(".audioplayer").remove(), cleanActiveClasses(), e.find(".playlist-item").eq(a.index()).addClass("playlist-item-play");
  var t = a.find(".ms-author").text(),
    i = a.find(".ms-song").text(),
    l = a.find(".ms-image img").attr("src"),
    s = a.find(".ms-save-song").data("mp3");


  $(".main-player").append('<audio preload="auto" class="play-song"><source src="' + s + '" /></audio>'), $(".main-player").find("audio").audioPlayer(), "undefined" != l && $(".mplayer-image").append('<img src="' + l + '" alt="" />'), $(".main-player .mplayer-title u").append(t), $(".main-player .mplayer-title i").append(i), $(window).width() <= "1250" && $(".player-wrap").addClass("miniplayer")
}

function loadPlayList() {
  var a = $(".favlink").attr("href");



  $.ajax({
    url: a,
    type: "get",
    cache: !0,
    success: function(a) {
      $($(a).find(".main-news")).each(function() {
        var a = $(this).find(".main-news-title").attr("href"),
          e = $(this).find(".main-news-author").text(),
          t = $(this).find(".main-news-song").text(),
          i = $(this).find(".ms-save-song").data("mp3"),
          l = $(this).find(".ms-image img").attr("src");


        $(".tabs-pl .plstab").append('<a href="' + a + '" class="playlist-item"><u class="ms-author">' + e + '</u><i class="ms-song">' + t + '</i><span class="ms-save-song" data-mp3="' + i + '"></span><span class="ms-image" style="display: none;"><img src="' + l + '" alt="" /></span></a>')
      })
    },
    complete: function(a) {
      $(".tabs-pl .tt-panel").mCustomScrollbar()
    }
  })
}

function addTempPlayList(a, e) {
  cleanTempPlayList(), $(a.find(e)).each(function() {
    var a = $(this).find(".ms-link").data("link"),
      e = $(this).find(".ms-author").text(),
      t = $(this).find(".ms-song").text(),
      i = $(this).find(".ms-save-song").data("mp3"),
      l = $(this).find(".ms-image img").attr("src");

    $(".tabs-pl .plstemp").append('<a href="' + a + '" class="playlist-item"><u class="ms-author">' + e + '</u><i class="ms-song">' + t + '</i><span class="ms-save-song" data-mp3="' + i + '"></span><span class="ms-image" style="display: none;"><img src="' + l + '" alt="" /></span></a>')
  })
}

function showPlay() {
  $(".main-player .audioplayer").removeClass("audioplayer-stopped").addClass("audioplayer-playing")
}

function playNext() {
  if ($(".playlist-item-play").length) var a = $(".playlist-item-play"),
    e = $(".playlist-item-play").parent();
  else a = $(".playlist-item:first"), e = $(".playlist-item:first").parent();
  if (0 == playRandom) {
    createPlaySong(t = a.next(".playlist-item").length ? a.next(".playlist-item") : e.find(".playlist-item:first")), t.addClass("playlist-item-play"), $(".main-player").find("audio").get(0).play(), showPlay()
  } else {
    var t, i = e.find(".playlist-item").length,
      l = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * (i + 1 - 1));
    createPlaySong(t = e.find(".playlist-item").eq(l - 1)), t.addClass("playlist-item-play"), $(".main-player").find("audio").get(0).play(), showPlay()
  }
}

function playPrev() {
  if ($(".playlist-item-play").length) var a = $(".playlist-item-play"),
    e = $(".playlist-item-play").parent();
  else a = $(".playlist-item:first"), e = $(".playlist-item:first").parent();
  var t = a.prev(".playlist-item").length ? a.prev(".playlist-item") : e.find(".playlist-item:last");
  createPlaySong(t), t.addClass("playlist-item-play"), $(".main-player").find("audio").get(0).play(), showPlay()
}

function showStatusWin(a) {
  $("body").append('<div class="status-win">' + a + "</div>"), $(".status-win").fadeIn(400).delay(2e3).fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(".status-win").remove()
  })
}
playRepeat = !1, playRandom = !1,
  function(a, e, t, i) {
    var l = "ontouchstart" in e,
      s = l ? "touchstart" : "mousedown",
      n = l ? "touchmove" : "mousemove",
      o = l ? "touchcancel" : "mouseup",
      p = function(a) {
        var e = a / 3600,
          t = Math.floor(e),
          i = a % 3600 / 60,
          l = Math.floor(i),
          s = Math.ceil(a % 3600 % 60);
        return s > 59 && (s = 0, l = Math.ceil(i)), l > 59 && (l = 0, t = Math.ceil(e)), (0 == t ? "" : t > 0 && t.toString().length < 2 ? "0" + t + ":" : t + ":") + (l.toString().length < 2 ? "0" + l : l) + ":" + (s.toString().length < 2 ? "0" + s : s)
      },
      d = function(a) {
        var e = t.createElement("audio");
        return !(!e.canPlayType || !e.canPlayType("audio/" + a.split(".").pop().toLowerCase() + ";").replace(/no/, ""))
      };
    a.fn.audioPlayer = function(e) {
      e = a.extend({
        classPrefix: "audioplayer",
        strPlay: "Play",
        strPause: "Pause",
        strVolume: "Volume"
      }, e);
      var t = {},
        i = {
          playPause: "playpause",
          playing: "playing",
          stopped: "stopped",
          time: "time",
          timeCurrent: "time-current",
          timeDuration: "time-duration",
          bar: "bar",
          barLoaded: "bar-loaded",
          barPlayed: "bar-played",
          volume: "volume",
          volumeButton: "volume-button",
          volumeAdjust: "volume-adjust",
          noVolume: "novolume",
          muted: "muted",
          mini: "mini"
        };
      for (var r in i) t[r] = e.classPrefix + "-" + i[r];
      return this.each(function() {
        if ("audio" != a(this).prop("tagName").toLowerCase()) return !1;
        var i = a(this),
          r = i.attr("src"),
          m = "" === (m = i.get(0).getAttribute("autoplay")) || "autoplay" === m,
          u = "" === (u = i.get(0).getAttribute("loop")) || "loop" === u,
          y = !1;
        void 0 === r ? i.find("source").each(function() {
          if (void 0 !== (r = a(this).attr("src")) && d(r)) return y = !0, !1
        }) : d(r) && (y = !0);
        var c = a('<div class="' + e.classPrefix + '">' + (y ? a("<div>").append(i.eq(0).clone()).html() : '<embed src="' + r + '" width="0" height="0" volume="100" autostart="' + m.toString() + '" loop="' + u.toString() + '" />') + '<div class="mplayer-image"></div><div class="mplayer-nav"><div class="mplayer-prev"></div><div class="mplayer-pp ' + t.playPause + '" title="' + e.strPlay + '" rel="' + e.strPlay + '"></div><div class="mplayer-next"></div></div>'),
          f = (f = y ? c.find("audio") : c.find("embed")).get(0);
        if (y) {
          c.find("audio").css({
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
            visibility: "hidden"
          }), c.append('<div class="mplayer-center"><div class="mplayer-title"><u></u><i></i></div><div class="mplayer-line"><div class="mplayer-line-left ' + t.time + " " + t.timeCurrent + '"></div><div class="' + t.bar + '"><div class="' + t.barLoaded + '"></div><div class="' + t.barPlayed + '"></div></div><div class="mplayer-line-right ' + t.time + " " + t.timeDuration + '"></div></div></div><div class="mplayer-right"><div class="' + t.volume + '"><div class="' + t.volumeButton + '" title="' + e.strVolume + '" title="Громкость"><a href="#"></a>Громкость <i>100%</i></div><div class="' + t.volumeAdjust + '"><div><div></div></div></div></div></div>');
          var v = c.find("." + t.bar),
            h = c.find("." + t.barPlayed),
            $ = c.find("." + t.barLoaded),
            g = c.find("." + t.timeCurrent),
            b = c.find("." + t.timeDuration),
            C = c.find("." + t.volumeButton),
            w = c.find("." + t.volumeAdjust + " > div"),
            P = 0,
            x = function(a) {
              theRealEvent = l ? a.originalEvent.touches[0] : a, f.currentTime = Math.round(f.duration * (theRealEvent.pageX - v.offset().left) / v.width())
            },
            k = function(a) {
              theRealEvent = l ? a.originalEvent.touches[0] : a, f.volume = Math.abs((theRealEvent.pageX - (w.offset().left + w.width())) / w.width()), f.volume = Math.abs(1 - f.volume)
            },
            S = f.volume,
            L = f.volume = .111;
          Math.round(1e3 * f.volume) / 1e3 == L ? f.volume = S : c.addClass(t.noVolume), b.html("&hellip;"), g.html(p(0)), f.addEventListener("loadeddata", function() {
            var e;
            e = setInterval(function() {
              if (f.buffered.length < 1) return !0;


              $.width(f.buffered.end(0) / f.duration * 100 + "%"), Math.floor(f.buffered.end(0)) >= Math.floor(f.duration) && clearInterval(e)
            }, 100), b.html(a.isNumeric(f.duration) ? p(f.duration) : "&hellip;"), w.find("div").width(100 * f.volume + "%"), P = f.volume
          }), f.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
            g.html(p(f.currentTime)), h.width(f.currentTime / f.duration * 100 + "%")
          }), a("body").on("click", w, function() {
            w.find("div").width(100 * f.volume + "%"), f.volume > 0 && c.hasClass(t.muted) && c.removeClass(t.muted), f.volume <= 0 && !c.hasClass(t.muted) && c.addClass(t.muted), c.find(".audioplayer-volume-button i").empty().append((100 * f.volume).toFixed(0) + "%")
          }), f.addEventListener("ended", function() {
            c.removeClass(t.playing).addClass(t.stopped), a("div").removeClass("play-active"), 0 == playRepeat ? playNext() : (a(".main-player").find("audio").get(0).play(), a(".main-player .audioplayer").removeClass("audioplayer-stopped").addClass("audioplayer-playing"))
          }), v.on(s, function(a) {
            x(a), v.on(n, function(a) {
              x(a)
            })
          }).on(o, function() {
            v.unbind(n)
          }), C.on("click", function() {
            return c.hasClass(t.muted) ? (c.removeClass(t.muted), f.volume = P) : (c.addClass(t.muted), P = f.volume, f.volume = 0), !1
          }), w.on(s, function(a) {
            k(a), w.on(n, function(a) {
              k(a)
            })
          }).on(o, function() {
            w.unbind(n)
          })
        } else c.addClass(t.mini);
        c.addClass(m ? t.playing : t.stopped), c.find("." + t.playPause).on("click", function() {
          a(this).parent().parent().attr("class");
          return c.hasClass(t.playing) ? (a(this).attr("title", e.strPlay).find("a").html(e.strPlay), c.removeClass(t.playing).addClass(t.stopped), y ? f.pause() : f.Stop()) : (a(this).attr("title", e.strPause).find("a").html(e.strPause), c.addClass(t.playing).removeClass(t.stopped), y ? f.play() : f.Play()), !1
        }), i.replaceWith(c)
      }), this
    }
  }(jQuery, window, document), $(document).ready(function() {
    addTempPlayList($(".stm-block-content"), $(".main-news")), $(".playlist-item:first").addClass("playlist-item-play"), createPlaySong($(".main-news:first")), loadPlayList(), $("body").on("click", ".mplayer-next", function() {
      playNext()
    }), $("body").on("click", ".mplayer-prev", function() {
      playPrev()
    }), $("body").on("click", ".mplayer-menu-rep", function() {
      playRandom = !1, playRepeat = !playRepeat, $(".mplayer-menu-rnd").removeClass("mplayer-menu-active"), $(this).toggleClass("mplayer-menu-active")
    }), $("body").on("click", ".mplayer-menu-rnd", function() {
      playRepeat = !1, playRandom = !playRandom, $(".mplayer-menu-rep").removeClass("mplayer-menu-active"), $(this).toggleClass("mplayer-menu-active")
    }), $("body").on("click", ".playlist-item", function() {
      cleanActiveClasses();
      var a = $(this);
      return createPlaySong(a), cleanActiveClasses(), a.addClass("playlist-item-play"), $(".main-player").find("audio").get(0).play(), showPlay(), $(".mobplaeyr .audioplayer").addClass("audioplayer-opacity"), !1
    }), $("body").on("click", ".slider-item-image", function() {
      return cleanActiveClasses(), addTempPlayList($(".sld1 .swiper-wrapper"), $(".slider-item")), createPlaySong($(this).parent()), $(".main-player").find("audio").get(0).play(), showPlay(), !1
    }), $("body").on("click", ".main-news-play", function() {
      addTempPlayList($(".ajax-content"), $(".main-news")), createPlaySong($(this).parent()), $(".main-player").find("audio").get(0).play(), $("div").removeClass("play-active"), $(this).parent().toggleClass("play-active"), showPlay()
    }), $("body").on("click", ".full-news-listen a", function() {
      return createPlaySong($(this)), $(".main-player").find("audio").get(0).play(), showPlay(), !1
    }), $("body").on("click", ".main-news-pause", function() {
      $(".main-player").find("audio").get(0).pause(), $("div").removeClass("play-active")
    }), $("body").on("click", ".mplayer-menu-playlist, .player-popup-close", function() {
      $(".player-popup").slideToggle(), $(".audioplayer, .mobplaeyr-close").toggleClass("audioplayer-opacity")
    }), $("body").on("click", ".mob-playr-open, .mobplaeyr-close", function() {
      $(".player-wrap").toggleClass("mobplaeyr")
    }), $("body").on("click", ".mplayer-menu-zoom1", function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("mplayer-menu-active"), $(".player-wrap").toggleClass("miniplayer")
    }), $("body").on("click", ".fav-js", function() {
      if ($(".plstab .playlist-item-play").length) var a = $(".playlist-item-play .ms-save-song").data("mp3");

      $(".plstab").empty();
      var e = $(".favlink").attr("href");


      $.ajax({
        url: e,
        type: "get",
        cache: !0,
        success: function(a) {
          $($(a).find(".main-news")).each(function() {
            var a = $(this).find(".main-news-title").attr("href"),
              e = $(this).find(".main-news-author").text(),
              t = $(this).find(".main-news-song").text(),
              i = $(this).find(".ms-save-song").data("mp3");

            $(".tabs-pl .plstab").append('<a href="' + a + '" class="playlist-item"><u class="ms-author">' + e + '</u><i class="ms-song">' + t + '</i><span class="ms-save-song" data-mp3="' + i + '"></span></a>')
          })
        },
        complete: function(e) {
          void 0 !== a && $(".plstab").find('.ms-save-song[data-mp3="' + a + '"]').parent().addClass("playlist-item-play")
        }
      })
    }), $("body").on("click", ".singer-play", function() {
      $(".plstemp").empty();
      var a = $(this).parent().find(".singer-track a").attr("href");
      "undefined" != a && $.ajax({
        url: a,
        type: "get",
        cache: !0,
        success: function(a) {
          $(".loading-popup").addClass("loading-content"), $($(a).find('div[data-cat="song"]')).each(function() {
            var a = $(this).find(".main-news-title").attr("href"),
              e = $(this).find(".main-news-author").text(),
              t = $(this).find(".main-news-song").text(),
              i = $(this).find(".ms-save-song").data("mp3");

            $(".tabs-pl .plstemp").append('<a href="' + a + '" class="playlist-item"><u class="ms-author">' + e + '</u><i class="ms-song">' + t + '</i><span class="ms-save-song" data-mp3="' + i + '"></span></a>')
          })
        },
        complete: function(a) {
          createPlaySong($(".plstemp .playlist-item:first")), $(".main-player").find("audio").get(0).play(), cleanActiveClasses(), $(".playlist-item:first").addClass("playlist-item-play"), showPlay(), $(".loading-popup").removeClass("loading-content"), showStatusWin("Треки загружены в плейлист")
        }
      })
    }), $("body").on("click", ".albums-play", function() {
      $(".plstemp").empty();
      var a = $(this).parent().find(".albums-title a").attr("href");
      "undefined" != a && $.ajax({
        url: a,
        type: "get",
        cache: !0,
        success: function(a) {
          $(".loading-popup").addClass("loading-content"), $($(a).find('div[data-cat="song"]')).each(function() {
            var a = $(this).find(".main-news-title").attr("href"),
              e = $(this).find(".main-news-author").text(),
              t = $(this).find(".main-news-song").text(),
              i = $(this).find(".ms-save-song").data("mp3");

            $(".tabs-pl .plstemp").append('<a href="' + a + '" class="playlist-item"><u class="ms-author">' + e + '</u><i class="ms-song">' + t + '</i><span class="ms-save-song" data-mp3="' + i + '"></span></a>')
          })
        },
        complete: function(a) {
          createPlaySong($(".plstemp .playlist-item:first")), $(".main-player").find("audio").get(0).play(), cleanActiveClasses(), $(".playlist-item:first").addClass("playlist-item-play"), showPlay(), $(".loading-popup").removeClass("loading-content"), showStatusWin("Треки загружены в плейлист")
        }
      })
    })
  });
```

Comment: воспроизведение не зависит от разрешения, а зависит от того, что отдается по запросу, если отдается действительно json - ты его никак не проиграешь, нужно его получать и смотреть что именно ты можешь передать в плеер

Comment: как ты делаешь запрос? со своего сайта?